# What does this mean,"Reinvigorating Human Capital"?

Tags: taxes, investing, india, budget, money-market

This was one of the six pillars of the Union Budget for the year 2021 for my country.It would be great if someone can explain me this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a term that refers to human productivity and experience.  Here's a great definition for it from Investopedia:

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/humancapital.asp

They're saying they want to get people motivated to be productive again, basically.